# Javascript not running when onclick is called

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Other onclicks in general seem fine, this paticular one will not run and I can't think why.

The HTML (From inside a PHP echo)

```
<div class=\"f_love_it\">
<button id=\"f_love_it_{$type}_{$currant_id}\" class=\"btn btn-primary\" onclick=\"love_it({$_SESSION['user_id']},{$currant_id},{$type},{$post["user_id"]})\">I Love It!
</button></div>
```

The Pure HTML

```
<button id="f_love_it_comment_16" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="love_it(4,16,comment,1)">I Love It!</button>
```

The Script

```
function love_it(lover_id,loved_id,post_type,poster_id)
{
    alert("You moose");
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var get_request = "/lib/love.php?lover_id="+lover_id+"&loved_id="+loved_id+"&type="+post_type+"&poster_id="+poster_id;
    var element_id = 'f_love_it_'+post_type+'_'+loved_id;

    document.getElementById(element_id).innerHTML = 'Yup';

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById(element_id).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", get_request, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: If that's your HTML, why the backslashes?

Comment: Oh that is from inside an echo, prints correctly on the actual page.

Comment: So, I assume you're not seeing the alert for "You moose"? Can we see the HTML after it's been printed to the page?

Comment: Then please copy the *actual* output here, not the PHP.

Comment: Ding, ding, ding. `onclick="love_it(4,16,comment,1)"` Notice anything wrong there?

Comment: Ah you got it! Strings need ''. I would not have considered that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is comment a variable or the actual string?

```
onclick="love_it(4,16,comment,1)"
```

If it is a variable it is correct, if it is a string, well you are missing quotes to make it a string.

```
onclick="love_it(4,16,'comment',1)"
```

Now is the "comment" has a ' or " in it, that will fail.

Answer (score 1):

```
onclick=\"love_it({$_SESSION['user_id']},{$currant_id},{$type},{$post["user_id"]})\"
```

This snippet seems to contain some PHP. Check it's output in your HTML, because it seems to be incorrect. You mix single and double quotes, and you spelt `currant_id`, which I guess should be `current_id`, unless you want to identify a berry.

In general, if your Javascript isn't running, check the Javascript in the browser and track back any mistakes to your PHP code. That will be much easier than evaluating your PHP code and guessing the error. Your browser probably has a console (press F12) that shows you Javascript runtime errors.

**[edit]**

After seeing your added output, I conclude that `post_type` need to be quoted.

```
love_it(4,16,comment,1)
```

should be

```
love_it(4,16,'comment',1)
```

So the code should be:

```
<button id=\"f_love_it_{$type}_{$currant_id}\" class=\"btn btn-primary\" onclick=\"love_it({$_SESSION['user_id']},{$currant_id},'{$type}',{$post["user_id"]})\">I Love It!
```

Comment: Some other countries actually spell it `currant` apparently. I've seen that a lot with non-english speakers code.

Comment: I posted the HTML as it is outputted, and fixed that spelling mistake, although it should have had no effect.

Comment: I see. I've updated my answer. I think you forgot some quotes.